# FingerPrinting Indoor Positioning Map Creation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, maps, ibeacon

I have to create an indoor navigation application, for this i am using fingerprinting technique with the iBeacons. I would like to know that how can i create the indoor map with reference points for fingerprinting or how can i do fingerprinting on the indoor maps. How can i do that on google maps or OSM.
Every example of fingerprinting guides me to do it on an image.. :/
But i want to make an interactive map, where i can navigate and zoom and get information and directions like google maps.

Please guide me how can i create a map for fingerprinting.

Answer (score 0):

The term "fingerprinting" means something very specific when it comes to indoor location.  It refers to taking a large number of measurements of the signal strength to various Bluetooth beacons (or WiFi access points) at specific points in a room or other space.  A "fingerprint" at a single point in the room refers to the expected signal strength of each transmitter when the device is at that location.  The process of "fingerprinting" refers to doing a survey of the room, where you measure the "fingerprint" at a large number of reference points so apps can determine which point they are near at a later time.

This question sounds like it is specific to how a mobile device's location, once determined, is represented on a map.  (Or perhaps the question is about how the reference points of the fingerprinting process can be represented on a map?)  Either way, there are plenty of examples out there of how to plot points on a Google map based on their latitude/longitude combinations.  The specifics of how you do so depends on the platform you are using (web, iOS, Android, etc.)

Comment: I meant that how to add those fingerprint reference points on any(Google) indoor map. As GPS i guess is no accurate for small distance points.

Comment: The way you put points on a Google map is different depending on whether you are building an iOS app, an Android app or a web app.   Which are you doing?